# Time difference for a particular product

Tags: mysql

Essentially, I want to find out how much time is spent on a product.
Each product is identified by the model_id and different people may work on
each product. I want the time difference between when the product is being worked on and when there is more than a 5 minute gap.

## example table

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, created_at DATETIME, model_id INT, TIMEDIFF DATETIME, TOTALTIME DATETIME)


SELECT '144111', '2019-03-30 11:14:26','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144112', '2019-03-30 11:14:33','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144113', '2019-03-30 11:14:33','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144114', '2019-03-30 11:14:54','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144115', '2019-03-30 11:15:35','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144116', '2019-03-30 11:22:21','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144117', '2019-03-30 11:23:14','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144118', '2019-03-30 11:24:24','301302','',''
UNION
SELECT '144119', '2019-03-30 11:25:35','301302','',''
```

## my attempt

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(model_id) FROM portal3_projectsolar.`qat_` WHERE `timediff` IS NULL) > 0 DO #begining of while loop

    #min modelid
    SET @modelid = (SELECT MIN(model_id) FROM `portal3_projectsolar`.`qat_` WHERE `Timediff` IS NULL);

    #set the times
    SET @starttime = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM `portal3_projectsolar`.`qat_` a WHERE a.model_id = @modelid AND a.`Timediff` IS NULL ORDER BY a.model_id, a.created_at);
    SET @endtime = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM `portal3_projectsolar`.`qat_` a WHERE a.model_id = @modelid AND a.created_at > @starttime AND a.`Timediff` IS NULL ORDER BY a.model_id, a.created_at);
    SET @Nexttime = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM `portal3_projectsolar`.`qat_` a WHERE a.model_id = @modelid AND a.created_at > @endtime AND a.`Timediff` IS NULL ORDER BY a.model_id, a.created_at);

    # compare the endtime and the nexttime. if nextime is 5 minutes more than endtime then endtime is endtime       
    WHILE (SELECT DATE_ADD(@endtime,INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) > @Nextdate) DO

        SET @Endtime =(SELECT @Nexttime); 
        SET @Nexttime = (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM `portal3_projectsolar`.`qat_` WHERE model_id = @modelid AND created_at > @endtime AND `Timediff` IS NULL ORDER BY model_id, created_at);

    END WHILE;

    #the time diffrence
    SET @timediff = (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @starttime, @endtime));
    SET @startid = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM qat_ WHERE created_at = @starttime);
    SET @endid = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM qat_ WHERE created_at = @endtime);

    #update the time diff for the id range
    UPDATE portal3_projectsolar.`qat_`
    SET `timediff` = @timediff
    WHERE Created_at = BETWEEN @starttime AND @Endtime;


END WHILE;
```

The results should show the difference of the start and end in the timediff column and the total time spent for each model_id in the totaltime column

Comment: I think there's problem here... I assume `created_at` is when a user starts working on a product. But when it finishing? Where is this data? What if user starts working on A product than he finishing and starts working on B than again A. In this case there will be even more time between the two A timestamp... I guess you need first to change the database table. You can't even determinate from this data if the user A or B owns that record. I guessing you need the following data structure: `id, start timestamp, end timestamp, user id, product id`. Than you can get the diff by `end - start`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to do what you want with these data, at least it won't fulfill your criteria. You can get only the time difference between a specific product work was started, but it doesn't say, who started on (maybe two different people) and if there was another work on a different product from the same person.

Comment: i understand what your saying but i dont actually want to use userid i simply want to use the time if the nexttime is greater than 5 min then the previous time is the end. I hope that makes sense